Use a variable to define another variable
I am trying to define a variable using another variable's numeric value in a 3x3 display, and the user will input a keystroke that will "move" a cursor (in this case O) and be able to select something.
## $1-$9 are set to _

if (y) {$hello = 4}
if (x) {$hello = 6}

$[$hello] = "O" 

$1$2$3
$4$5$6
$7$8$9


PowerShell does not have native "variable variable" syntax - you'll need to take advantage of either the Set-Variable cmdlet, or use the provider cmdlets against the Variable:\ drive:
$hello = 6
Set-Variable -Name $hello -Value 'O'
# or 
'O' |Set-Content -Path Variable:\$hello


Instead of using individual variables to store each cell state, consider using an array:
$width = 3
# create an array consisting of 3x3 strings `_`
$cells = ,'_' * ($width * $width)

Now you can use the variable directly in an index operation:
$hello = 4

# array indices are 0-based in .NET, so it goes 0-8, not 1-9
$cells[$hello - 1] = 'O'

To print the grid:
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $width; $i++) {
    # calculate row offset
    $offset = $i * $width
    # collect cells in row, print as one line
    $cells[$offset..($offset + $width - 1)] -join ''
}

... and now it's trivial to refactor for use with 2x2, 4x4, 5x5 grids etc. :)
